# How to crawl whole website by following links using CrawlSpider?

Tags: scrapy

I realized that using `CrawlSpider` with a `LinkExtractor` rule only parses the linked pages but not the starting page itself.

For example, if `http://mypage.test` contains links to `http://mypage.test/cats/` and `http://mypage.test/horses/`, the crawler would parse the cats and horses page without parsing `http://mypage.test`. Here's a simple code sample:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://mypage.test']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_page(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url,
            'status': response.status,
        }


process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'pipelines.MyPipeline': 100,
    },
})
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

My goal is to parse every single page in a website by following links. How do I accomplish that?

Apparently, `CrawlSpider` with a `LinkExtractor` rule only parses the linked pages but not the starting page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `start_urls` and add:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request('http://mypage.test', callback="parse_page")
    yield Request("http://mypage.test", callback="parse")
```

`CrawlSpider` uses `self.parse` to extract and follow links.

Comment: Could you explain why two `yields` are needed? The first `yield` is for parsing the starting page only, and the second `yield` is to put the `CrawlSpider` into motion. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can follow the code of `Spider` class in `spiders/__init__.py`, `start_requests` makes requests from `self.start_urls`, with default callback to `self.parse` which was defined in `CrawlerSpider` that do the link extraction and yield new requests from each link.